# Errors on codeceptjs tests as - 'Statement Expected' , 'Epression Expected'

Tags: javascript, webdriver, codeceptjs

I have configured codeceptjs and while writing the first test I am getting some errors which I could not figure out, the code is as below.

But the strange thing is it is executing perfectly. but i want to make sure why it is an error there. Am I missing anything in configuration or any other?
[image: attached here]

Config File:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm think you are declined request of creating a custom actor when installation of codeceptjs:

> ? Where would you like to place custom steps? (./steps_file.js)

steps_file.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';
// in this file you can append custom step methods to 'I' object

module.exports = function() {
  return actor({

    // Define custom steps here, use 'this' to access default methods of I.
    // It is recommended to place a general 'login' function here.

  });
}
```

You can try create this file or remove `"I": "./steps_file.js"` from your configuration.